# Return the for-loops and print txt file

Tags: ruby, return, argv

I am trying a code, that will open a file when the for - loops method will generate letters and when this letters will be join together and form 'abcd' this will return the script and print the txt file.
I have tried different possibilities but for the moment only have been able to stop the script and to print all the time letters, also printed the file. But never have been able to make all working together.

```
def words(target)
  filename = ARGV.first

 txt = open(filename)

  ('a'..'z').each do |i|
    ('a'..'z').each do |j|
      ('a'..'z').each do |h|
        ('a'..'z').each do |g|

   together = i+j+h+g
   print together

case together
 when together == target
  return print txt.read

           end
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end

words("abcd")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the desired input/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how `case` works, you should use `if` instead:

```
def words(target)
  filename = ARGV.first

 txt = open(filename)

  ('a'..'z').each do |i|
    ('a'..'z').each do |j|
      ('a'..'z').each do |h|
        ('a'..'z').each do |g|
          together = i+j+h+g
          print together

          if together == target
            return print txt.read
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

words("abcd")
```

Or, if you insist on using `case` (for some reason):

```
case together
  when target
    return print txt.read
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried with if as well but still did not work as supposed. I don't know where it actually failed with the if as I think I tried that option don't, anyways thank you very much

Comment: It works for me, i.e. prints all combinations of letters, starting from `aaaa` to `abcd` and then prints the file's contents. Isn't that what you described in the question?

Comment: Yes that was what I wanted, don't know where it was failing but printing the letters and return and print the txt file was not happening. Now all good

Answer (score 1):

```
('a'..'z').
  to_a.
  repeated_permutation(4).
  map(&:join).
  detect { |w| w == target }
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `repeated_permutation`. Nice!